Evaluating $ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e - (1 + 2x)^{1/2x}}{x} $ without using any expansion series
The following is a question from the Joint Entrance Examination (Main) from the 09 April 2024 evening shift:

$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e - (1 + 2x)^{1/2x}}{x} $$ is equal to:
(A) $0$
(B) $\frac{-2}{e}$
(C) $e$
(D) $e - e^2$

I rearranged the problem to this:

$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e - e^{\log(1 + 2x)/(2x)}}{x} $$

And tried to evaluate the limit, but I am stuck. I don't want the solution, a pointer towards the right way is sufficient. Please try not to evaluate using any expansion series, unless it's absolutely impossible to solve the limit without using it. Any other methods are welcome.

Have you tried L'Hôpital's?

What is your definition of $e$?

L'Hopital's rule will work.  Also remember that $\lim_{z \to 0} (1+z)^{1/z} = e$, which might be more familiar in the form $\lim_{x \to \infty} (1+1/x)^x = e$.

Can anyone please tell me exactly what I can do to reopen my question, and if I can do anything at all?

Your start is good, then we can proceed as follows
$$\frac{e - (1 + 2x)^{1/2x}}{x}=\frac{e - e^{\frac{\log(1 + 2x)}{2x}}}{x}=e\cdot \frac{1 - e^{\frac{\log(1 + 2x)}{2x}-1}}{x} $$
and then using standard limit $\frac{e^x-1}x\to 1$ and $\frac{\log(1+x)-x}{x^2}\to -\frac12$ (see here).

First of all, substitute $2x\mapsto x$, so the limit becomes:
$$L=\frac12\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e-(1+x)^{1/x}}x=\frac e2\lim_{x\to 0}\frac 1x\left( 1- \exp\left(\frac1x\log(1+x)-1\right)\right) $$
Now note that $\frac1x\log(1+x)-1\to 0$ and use the fact that
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^{f(x)}-1}{f(x)}=1 \quad \text{if}\quad f(x)\to 0$$
Letting $f(x)=\frac1x\log(1+x)-1$ you have:
$$L=-\frac e2\lim_{x\to 0}\frac1x \frac{e^{f(x)}-1}xf(x)=-\frac e2\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\log(1+x)-x}{x^2}=e$$
To evaluate the last limit without series expansion, see for example this question.
